# How to calculate Frequency for a column where consists integers and blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like below, it has 10000+ rows
[enter link description here](https://%22C:%5CUsers%5Clulu_%5COneDrive%5CDocuments%5Crun_2021.csv%22)
ID       Ref_r
235R23   3
56982B   3
62C879   blank
625478   11
9S4284   11
985U12   11
524555   58
99L852   60
1024T4   58
102W49   3
258q34   blank
.....

```
I'd like to calculate the frequency for col Ref_r (1 to 99), where consists integers and blanks:
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df['Ref_r']. value_counts()

````
however it doesn't work....

Expected result would be:
```none
Ref_r    Frequency
1           0
2           0
3           3
...
11          3
...
58          2
59          0
60          1
99          0
blank       2
````

Comment: Include the code you have tried so far, and mention what problem are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) with:

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep='\s+', dtype='str')['Ref_r']
 .value_counts(sort=False)
 .reindex(list(map(str, range(1,100)))+['blank'], fill_value=0)
 .rename_axis('Ref_r')
 .reset_index(name='Frequency')
 .to_csv('out.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
)
```

Example output:

```
Ref_r   Frequency
1   0
2   0
3   3
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  3
12  0
...
98  0
99  0
blank   2
```

Comment: Hi mozway, please help my error.  Input In [1] in <cell line: 2>
data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\lgrand\\OneDrive \\Documents\\run_2021.csv", sep='\s+', dtype='str')['Ref_r'].value_counts(sort=False).reindex(list(map(str, range(1,100)))+['blank'], fill_value=0).rename_axis('Ref_r').reset_index(name='Frequency').to_csv('out.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
  
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 4, saw 6

Comment: Please provide a sample of `run_2021.csv` **as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74209323/edit) to the question**

Comment: Hi mozway, I added a pic for the csv. the file is very big has more than 600 col. thank you very much!

Comment: A picture is not helpful, a **sample** as **text** is needed

Comment: Hi mozway, I just added a file as example. thank you.